# C# Linq Grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I'm experimenting with Linq and am having trouble figuring out grouping. I've gone through several tutorials but for some reason can't figure this out.

As an example, say I have a table (SiteStats) with multiple website IDs that stores a count of how many visitors by type have accessed each site in total and for the past 30 days.

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ SiteId ║ VisitorType ║ Last30 ║ Total║
╠════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════╣
║      1 ║           1 ║     10 ║  100 ║
║      1 ║           2 ║     40 ║  140 ║
║      2 ║           1 ║     20 ║  180 ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩════════╩══════╝
```

In SQL, I can easily get the counts for SiteID 1 with the following:

```
SELECT SiteId,  
       SUM(Last30) AS Last30Sum  
FROM Sites  
WHERE SiteId = 1  
GROUP BY SiteId
```

and should get a row like...

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║ SiteId ║ Last30Total║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║      1 ║         50 ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```

However I'm not sure how to get this result using Linq.  I've tried:

```
var statsRecord = from ss in db.SiteStats  
    where ss.SiteId == siteId  
    group ss by ss.SiteId into ss  
    select ss;
```

but I'm not able to get back the total with something like `statsRecord.Last30`

Can someone please let me know where I'm going wrong?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually, although Thomas' code will work, it is more succint to use a lambda expression:

```
var totals =
from s in sites
group s by s.SiteID into grouped
select new
{
    SiteID = grouped.Key,
    Last30Sum = grouped.Sum( s => s.Last30 )
};
```

which uses the Sum extension method without the need for a nested LINQ operation.

as per the LINQ 101 examples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747.aspx#sumGrouped

Comment: Although the OP didn't ask, can you show us how this can be written in LINQ's method syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way for me to illustrate is using in-memory objects so it's clear what's happening. LINQ to SQL should be able to take that same LINQ query and translate it into appropriate SQL.

```
public class Site
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Site> sites = new List<Site>()
        {
            new Site() { SiteID = 1, VisitorType = 1, Last30 = 10, Total = 100, },
            new Site() { SiteID = 1, VisitorType = 2, Last30 = 40, Total = 140, },
            new Site() { SiteID = 2, VisitorType = 1, Last30 = 20, Total = 180, },
        };

        var totals =
            from s in sites
            group s by s.SiteID into grouped
            select new
            {
                SiteID = grouped.Key,
                Last30Sum = 
                    (from value in grouped
                     select value.Last30).Sum(),
            };

        foreach (var total in totals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Site: {0}, Last30Sum: {1}", total.SiteID, total.Last30Sum);
        }
    }

    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int VisitorType { get; set; }
    public int Last30 { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```